# After applying rotate() translateX is moving up and down?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/mMPmXP

After applying `rotate(100deg)`, `translateX(-200)` is going up 200px instead. Why?

Is this because applying `ratate()` would change the origin or something? Is there anyway to "reset" this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beause `translateX()` is being computed after `rotate()`. When you rotate the element in a positive direction, the left edge is pointing upward, so moving it "left" moves it up instead.

If you want it to move to the left, move `translateX()` before `rotate()`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
  transform: translateX(-200px) rotate(110deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```